# Implementing condition in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I'm importing data from `txt` to `Sql Server table`. That part works good.

Everyday this `txt` file is being deleted and new `txt` file is formed (i.e. yesterday there was data for 3 February, today for 4 February (column `Date`)).

When I run package, I want it to check whether `Date` column exists in database table. If it exists, skip, don't import, if it doesn't - import. And I want to save that Date value in a `variable` for further manipulations. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: can you give us more information about the column of your `table `? or your `File` ?

Comment: @downloaddowload, txt file has several columns, one of which is date. And database has exact same number of columns where Date field is of type smalldatetime. Txt File can contain inside it rows with only one date (3rd February or 4th Faebruary and so on, with different times). What kind of information do you actually want me to provide? and just importing values from txt to table works fine. What I want is to set condition, so when I ran package today it imports all values for 4th of February,and if I ran it today second time,it doesn't import anything , since that data already exists in tbl

Comment: what's is the format of your date ? and also it's store in column with data type is `datetime` ?

Comment: @downloaddowload in txt it is like this 25.01.2016 16:23:14, and in table it is smalldatetime

Comment: Can you please share how the data is in your file ?

Comment: @downloaddowload, normal tab delimited txt file. for instance, 25.01.2016 16:23:14  ABC XXX ZZZ. How can that help. Maybe I didn't get something, if it necessary I'll attachscreenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we suppose you have your source file with the format and data as bellow

```
id    | product         |  dateLoad
1     |  dell           |  25-01-2016 16:23:14 
2     |  hp             |  25-01-2016 16:23:15 
3     |  lenovo         |  25-01-2016 16:23:16
```

and your destination have the format as bellow

```
create table stack(id int,product varchar(20),dateLoad smalldatetime);
```

In your `SSIS` add a `Derived Column` to convert the `smalldatetime` to `date` like this :

[image: Convert smalldatetime to Date]

Secondly add a `Lookup` in `General` Tab in your `Lookup transformation Editor` go to `Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries` and select `Redirect rows to no match output`. In `Connection` Tab add a connection to target `table` and i wrote a `Sql query` to convert the `smalldatetime to date` show the picture as bellow :

[image: connection to the target table]

In `Column tab` do this :
[image]

Finally add a connection with the `lookup` and your `target table` and select `Lookup no matching output`

In the first execution i have `3 rows`inserted because i don't have the date in my table 
[image: First execution]

I execute another time but i had `0 rows` because i have the date in my `table`

[image]

I hope that help you

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. That worked great

Comment: one more question: how can I save that Date in a variable. I want to use that in Send Mail Task in subject like: "Info for 04/02/2016. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want stock the date that exist in file in the `variable` in my example is `25-01-2016` ?

Comment: yes, exactly. Package runs, after data flow completed, I add Send Mail Task, and I wnat to use that 25-01-2016 for Subject like "Info for 25-01-2016". I don't know how to save that variable

Comment: i think is better to do another question `How to save a string based in flat file into variable`

Comment: yeah, this interpretation is more valid